# MySQL Database Replication in Fedora 21

Tags: mysql, replication, linux

I have a MySQL 5.6 Community Edition server running on a machine with Fedora 21 which was installed via the YUM repository. I want to enable MySQL replication on the Server, but since I am limited to one machine, I have to install two MySQL instances on the same machine. I need a complete step-by-step procedure of installing two or more MySQL server instances side by side, one to act as the Master, the other as the slave. I have tried searching on the Internet for a comprehensive procedure, but I haven't found any yet. The MySQL Official documentation didn't really help as it is OS independent, yet I want a Fedora/Linux specific installation and configuration. Other links I have tried include (not in any specific order) [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Managing_Confined_Services/sect-Managing_Confined_Services-MySQL-Configuration_Examples.html) and [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/multiple-servers.html), but to no avail. Anyone with a complete reference/procedure on how to do this?

Comment: I guess the question is, why do you want to replicate to the same server? I don't believe you can install mysqld_multi from the standard YUM repos - you'll probably need to download the RPMs directly.

Comment: The Percona (a drop-in for MySQL) example seems pretty good: https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/08/26/mysqld_multi-how-to-run-multiple-instances-of-mysql/

Comment: @dwjv am in development, and am limited to a single machine

Comment: what I mean is, why do you need replication then?

Comment: Am developing a test system for vehicle tracking, whereby one db will be used for writes/updates and the other for reads/queries

Comment: Look into mysql sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an old instructions for [setting up master-master replication](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/quick-multi-mysql-server-installation-with-master-master-replication-on-same-windows-box) for windows but concept is same.
Considering you already have a 3306 instance by default you can follow below steps to setup as well (if above doesn't help)

> 1. Make datadir and correct permissions:
>      mkdir /var/lib/mysql3307
>      chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql3307
> 2. Create config 
>      cp /etc/my.cnf /etc/my3307.cnf (Correct relevant parameters)
> 3. Install basic auth system / dbs: 
>      mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql3307 --defaults-file=/etc/my3307.cnf
> 4. Start mysql  mysqld_safe --defaults-file=/etc/my3307.cnf --user=mysql &
> 5. Take fulldump from 3306 instance:  mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases --master-data=2 | gzip > backup.sql.gz
> 6. Load it to new 3307 instance 
>      zcat backup.sql.gz  | mysql -uroot -p --port=3307 --socket=/var/run/mysql/mysqld3307.sock
> 7. Grab binary log co-ordinates from  backup: 
>      zcat backup.sql.gz | head -30 | grep -i change
> 8. Create replication user on master: 
>      grant replication slave on *.* to 'repluser'@'%' identified by 'replpass';
> 9. Run change master to on 3307 slave using binlogs take from  step #7: 
>      CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='localhost', MASTER_USER='repluser', MASTER_PASSWORD='replpass', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_LOG_FILE='XXXX',
>      MASTER_LOG_POS=XXXX;
> 10. Start  slave on  3307.

You're done.

Comment: Yap, this worked!! Now, am trying to configure PHPMyAdmin to access the master instance but it gives me the "Cannot log in to the MySQL server" error. I have set up the port and socket in config.inc.php, but to no avail. Know how I can make it work?

Comment: can you connect from terminal?

Comment: yes I can, by first loading the defaults file to use, then by using the -S <path_to_socket> option i.e. `# mysql -S /var/lib/mysql_slave/mysql.sock`

Comment: Oh. never mind, I just solved it. Seems the problem was that SELinux was preventing Apache from creating socket connections. Once I allowed it, it worked like a charm!